# Is there a way to iterate through all of a shapes properties? (VBA WORD)

Tags: vba, properties, ms-word, shapes

I am trying to list all the properties of a selecting shape.
In my case it is a speech bubble that I would like to modify with a macro.
The following code doesn't work because Properties isn't a thing.

```
For Each prop In Selection.ShapeRange(1).Properties
Debug.Print prop.Name
Next
```

I would love to know how to do this. It would help tremendously.
Even a list of all properties a shape can have would be SUPER beneficial.

Comment: You mean like [the Object Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/use-the-object-browser), or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Wow! I didn't know this existed! Thanks! This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this isn't possible. But @Comintern commented on using [the Object Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/use-the-object-browser). Which really helped a lot.